# Как мне принять данные от promise?

Tags: javascript, promise

Есть функция window.lib.getPosts(), она возвращает Promise с данными, и мне нужно вывести эти данные в консоль, но каким образом это сделать?

```
window.lib.getPosts((error, articles) => {
      console.log(Promise);
      return error ? console.log(error) : console.log(articles);
    });
```

Читал документацию про Promise, не пойму каким образом ее впихнуть туда.

Если информации недостаточно, вот задание:
В скрипте доступна функция window.lib.getPosts (). Он возвращает обещание, которое будет разрешено после небольшой задержки со списком статей. Когда вы нажимаете на кнопку, вызываете функцию getPosts и отображаете полученные элементы в консоли (функция getPosts всегда будет разрешена без ошибок)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если функция возвращает промис, то необходимо записать промис  в переменную и обработать его

```
async function getData(){
    let response = await window.lib.getPosts();
    console.log(data);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Выдает вот такую ошибку:

Uncaught (in promise) Error: HTTP error! status: undefined
    at getData (script.js:17)

https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-shannon-fg5xg?file=/src/index.js если вам легче будет самим посмотреть

Comment: Там кажется проблема была в response.ok, убрал if else, и просто написал 
let response = await window.lib.getPosts()
let data = await response
console.log(data)

И заработало, благодарю!

Comment: поправил под ваш случай